# Powershell Try Catch which stops when external script fails

Tags: powershell, try-catch, dot-source

I have several powershell scripts that I am running from one powershell scripts.

I am using a try-catch to stop on errors. But that doesn't work with external scripts I'm calling. I cant use dot-source because some of the scripts require the 32 bit version of PowerShell (has to do with QuickBooks API call requiring 32bit)

So I am currently calling it using the full path name so i have something like this:

```
try {
# QB API requires powershell 32 bit: Open Sales Order by Item Report Call
& C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file  $ScriptDir\QB_API_Open_Sales_Orders_by_Item.ps1

# QB API requires powershell 32 bit: Inventory List Call
& C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file  $ScriptDir\QB_API_Inventory_List.ps1

# x64bit powershell: Convert QB_API Sales and Inventory Fiels from XML to CSV using XSLT
& C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file  $ScriptDir\transform_xml.ps1

# x64bit powershell: run vendor vs sales file to get final output
& C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file  $ScriptDir\Create_Sales_order_MPN_using_join.ps1
}
catch
{
Write-Warning $Error[0]
}
```

If I am dot-sourcing the scripts it works fine, but external calling it, it does not. Suggestions on how to catch the errors and stop the script?

Comment: @AdminOfThings why don't I want to call write-error automatically when the error occurs? does doing the 2>$null allow for the catch part to display the error?

Comment: You could evaluate the return codes of your external calls.

Comment: if the script sets `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`, then `$lastexitcode` would be a non-zero value on error in the calling shell.

Comment: If you want `try-catch` to work with executables in PowerShell session, then you must do the following: 1) Set `$errorActionPreference = 'stop'` so that all errors are terminating. 2) Redirect error stream elsewhere for the executable call -> `2>$null` for example. Then you can choose to call `Write-Error` if you want, but regardless, `$error[0]` will contain your exception.

Comment: if you put your comments in an answer ill mark it as correct. thank you for your help. setting the erroractionpreference to stop appears to have done the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want try-catch to work with executables in PowerShell session, then you must do the following:

1. Set `$errorActionPreference = 'stop'` so that all errors are terminating
2. Redirect error stream elsewhere for the executable call -> 2>$null for example.

```
$EAPBackup = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
try {
    C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file  $ScriptDir\QB_API_Open_Sales_Orders_by_Item.ps1 2>$null
} catch {
    Write-Warning $error[0]
}
$ErrorActionPreference = $EAPBackup
```

Comment: This trick does appear to work in Windows PowerShell 5.1, but it does now work in PowerShell 7.3.10 or PowerShell 7.4.0.